# REPOST: htaccess Error and Optimization

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can anybody help me optimize and fix my .htaccess file? I'm really bad at regex and I'm not a server person and site I'm building is inaccessible because of the error. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
SetEnv  _SRVR_ENV   beta

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## Paypal Callback Rules
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=(\w+-\w+)&PayerID=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(\w+)-(\w+)\.html                                /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&token=%1&payerid=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=(\w+-\w+)
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)\.html                          /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&token=%3 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} token=(\w+-\w+)
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(\w+)-(\w+)\.html                                /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&token=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} session=(.*) 
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(\w+)-(\w+)\.html                                /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&session=%1 [L]

## Custom Rules
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$   /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&v1=$4&v2=$6&v3=$8 [L]
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$             /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&v1=$4&v2=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.html$                       /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&v1=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(.*)-(.*)\.html$                                 /index.php?c=$1&m=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(.*)-(.*)\.html$                                 /index.php?c=$1&m=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^some-seo-text-(.*)\.html$                                      /index.php?c=$1 [L]

## Directory Cloaking
RewriteRule ^images/another-seo-text-(.*)$                                  /static/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^deals/another-seo-text-(.*)$                                   /static/images/campaigns/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$                                                      /static/stylesheets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$                                                       /static/javascripts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^captcha/(.*)$                                                  /static/captcha/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `(.*)` will happily match a `-` in an URL, making many of these matches ambiguous, and perhaps *very* slow. Your `\w` matches probably make more sense.

Can you paste the `diff(1)` between your last known good working `.htaccess` and this one? That would help you find the fault quickly.

Comment: thanks sarnold. I actually somehow fixed the error (I can't remember how) although optimization is really one of my priorities. Could you suggest how the codes above should be?

Comment: @Jhourlad Estrella, try replacing all your `(.*)` matches with `(\w+)` and try to see if that makes any improvement in rewriting speed / performance. Someone else may have better ideas for optimizing the rewriting rules, so you might want to open a new question and ask for advice optimizing. (Be prepared for someone to ask if what you have now is _actually a problem_ -- if it isn't noticeably slow, it probably isn't worth trying to improve. :)